# SwiftUI horizontal-scrolling ScrollView on watchOS cuts off content?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I have a ScrollView with an HStack of Rectangle objects (with a border just for visibility). Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4.0) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .border(Color.red, width: 8)
                        .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 140*3 + 4.0*3, height: 140)
        }
}
```

When I configure the ScrollView to allow horizontal and vertical scrolling (via the initializer `ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical])`), it sizes the objects appropriately and scrolls horizontally, while bouncing vertically:

[image: ScrollView on watchOS laying out correctly]

The bounce isn't ideal, though, so I'd like it to just scroll horizontally without bouncing vertically - but when I configure it to just allow horizontal scrolling (`ScrollView([.horizontal])`), it ends up cutting off the content at the bottom and scrolling vertically to display the content:

[image: ScrollView on watchOS cutting off content]

Before I submit this as a bug to Feedback Assistant, I wanted to make sure I'm not just missing something simple. I *did* see this note about ScrollViews in the release notes:

> A ScrollView doesn’t always size itself as expected for its content. (49204262)
>
> Workaround: Size the view that’s inside the ScrollView by applying the frame(width:height:alignment:) modifier to the inner view. (49204262)

But I did apply the `frame(width:height:alignment:)` modifier to the inner HStack, and it still cuts off in this situation, so I am wondering if this is another bug or if I'm missing something simple.